# Unity GameObject.SetActive doesn't not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote for my Game a Script that controls the Slots in the game by GameObject.
But the script isn't able to activate or deactivate. Everything is set up as it should, I also tried another Script but that works. The "main" script doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateBools();
        Crosshair();
        Slots();
    }
    void UpdateBools()
    {
        isPaused = PauseMenu.GamePaused;

    }
    public void Crosshair()
    {
        //Not important
    }
    public void Slots()
    {
        if (database.Slot1 != nothing)
        {
            Slot1.SetActive(true);
            Slot1Active = true;
        }
        else { Slot1.SetActive(false); }
        if (database.Slot2 != nothing)
        {
            Slot2.SetActive(true);
            Slot2Active = true;
        }
        else { Slot2.SetActive(false); }
        if (database.Slot3 != nothing)
        {
            Slot3.SetActive(true);
            Slot3Active = true;
        }
        else { Slot3.SetActive(false); }
        if (database.Slot4 != nothing)
        {
            Slot4.SetActive(true);
            Slot4Active = true;
        }
        else {
            Slot1.SetActive(false);
            Slot2.SetActive(false);
            Slot3.SetActive(false);
            Slot4.SetActive(false);
            Slot1Active = false;
            Slot2Active = false;
            Slot3Active = false;
            Slot4Active = false;
        }
    }
    public void SlotPic()
    {
        //I erased this because stack overflow says: mostly code, add more details but I have every detail
    }
```

It works like this: If one inventory slot is taken, it should be activated. For testing, I added ActivateEverything(). Also, the slot should change its picture when activated but as I said, activating the object doesn't work. Important for this task is the void Slots().

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511188/for-some-reason-gameobject-find-setactivetrue-doesnt-work-and-i-am-unsure-w/67511256#67511256)

Comment: In general poll check the states and (de)activate the objects each and every frame is a quite bad design .. rather make your code event driven

Comment: Also why do you deactivate **all** slots if only slot4 is nothing?

Comment: Also note that `Slot1Active` etc are quite redundant! Where needed simply check for `Slot1.activeSelf` etc

Comment: Thanks @derHugo , i just found out the code I made was crap. I'll rewrite it and then test again.

Answer (score -1):

Try to setActive without if else containers. Check if your gamemode not on pause.